# How to set floating point precision in Sklearn RocCurveDisplay?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, data-visualization

I want to set the floating-point precision of AUC (shown in the legend) to 4 digits. I used the default function available in `sklearn.metrics.RocCurveDisplay`:

```
RocCurveDisplay.from_predictions(
   y_test, y_preds, name="CNN")

plt.show()
```

I've got the matplotlib plot as,

[image]

I wish to change the AUC precision in the legend.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you cannot do it if using `RocCurveDisplay` as the print precision is hardcoded:

```py
        if self.roc_auc is not None and name is not None:
            line_kwargs["label"] = f"{name} (AUC = {self.roc_auc:0.2f})"
        elif self.roc_auc is not None:
            line_kwargs["label"] = f"AUC = {self.roc_auc:0.2f}"
        elif name is not None:
            line_kwargs["label"] = name
```

see https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09b/sklearn/metrics/_plot/roc_curve.py#L110

You need to plot the ROC curve in a more manual way, see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html and add the legend label with the precision you wish for.

Comment: Possibly, when more than 2 decimals are needed,  overfitting or some related problem are into play.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
RocCurveDisplay.from_predictions(
y_test, y_preds, name="CNN", label = 'CNN (AUC = 0.97xx')
```

to manually set you AUC the way you want. You still have to compute it manually though.